# Install .bat file

Tags: windows-xp, installation, command-prompt, psexec, batch-file

What I need to do is make a .bat script that will pull the install files from my server and launch them on a workstation to install a program, by a user on the workstation. There are 8 installs total for this 1 program and they have to be launched in order.

Any ideas on commands used to pull install files or how to use PS exec to install? I don't have anything to go with, all the research I did took me in other ways then making an install script.

Comment: so..do you want to install remotely or not? If remotely, then what kind of access would you have to those machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to figure it out on my own by playing around in cmd prompt. I tried a series of commands with no luck then I tried just the file paths separated by a pause and it worked so for anyone looking for a simple script to launch .exe's: (the quotations are if there are any spaces in the file path)
In cmd prompt or in notepad saved as a .bat file-

"\\000.00.00.00\programs\Apps\ProgramsBASELINE\cd install 01\setup.exe"

Pause

"\\000.00.00.00\programs\Apps\ProgramsBASELINE\cd install 02\setup.exe"

pause

"\\000.00.00.00\programs\Apps\ProgramsBASELINE\cd install 03\setup.exe"

pause

"\\000.00.00.00\programs\Apps\ProgramsBASELINE\cd install 04\setup.exe"

pause

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the `START /WAIT` command.  It will wait for each setup program to finish before beginning the next install, without the need for user interaction.  Putting a `PAUSE` in between each setup will force the user to press the enter key 4 times.  I'd also suggest looking into `PUSHD` if you want to run the bat file from a server and keep the bat file on the server along with the install programs. This way you could execute the bat file from the server, point it at whichever computer connected to the network you want, and run it.

ex (using START /WAIT):

```
@echo off

:CHECKIFTHISBATISRUNONSERVER
REM Checks to see if this bat file has been run from a server or from a local computer

IF NOT EXIST "%~nx0" (pushd %~dp0% & set batchfilemode=server) ELSE (set batchfilemode=local computer)

REM the lines below will start each program and wait for it to finish before starting the next setup.

START "SETUP 1" /WAIT "\\000.00.00.00\programs\Apps\ProgramsBASELINE\cd install 01\setup.exe"

START "SETUP 2" /WAIT "\\000.00.00.00\programs\Apps\ProgramsBASELINE\cd install 02\setup.exe"

START "SETUP 3" /WAIT "\\000.00.00.00\programs\Apps\ProgramsBASELINE\cd install 03\setup.exe"

START "SETUP 4" /WAIT "\\000.00.00.00\programs\Apps\ProgramsBASELINE\cd install 04\setup.exe"

POPD

EXIT /B
```